# conditional dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how to have that if you select something in my dropdown menu, It will write in the HTML 'You want .....'

Here is my code

```js
function latte1() {
  if (document.getElementById("latte").click) {
    alert("You like Latte")
  } else {
    document.write("You like Something else")
  }
}
```

```html
<option id="latte" onclick="latte1()">Latte</option>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: add `change` event on the `select` element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start with a `<select>` element which raises a `change` event when a selection is made. Inside that event, `this.value` refers to the selected value.

```js
var drinkSelect = document.getElementById("drink");
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
drinkSelect.addEventListener("change",function(){
  outputDiv.innerText = "You like " + this.value;
})
```

```html
<select id="drink">
  <option value="">Which drink would you like?</option>
  <option>Latte</option>
  <option>Capuccino</option>
  <option>Americano</option>
  <option>Tea</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
function latte1() {
  var latte = document.getElementById("latte");
  
  //the first latte below can be replaced with any other element
  latte.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p>" + (latte.click ? "You like Latte" : "You like Something else") + "</p>");
}
```

```html
<option id="latte" onclick="latte1()">Latte</option>
```

This code identifies an element in the page (in this case `#latte`) and addes a `<p>` element after it containing your text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want use select dropdown and show selected option

```js
function latte1(ele) {
  document.getElementById("selected_option").innerText = "You want " + ele.value;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="latte1(this)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
  <option value="Latte">Latte</option>
  <option value="Something else">Something else</option>
</select>
<p id="selected_option"></p>
```